# Geoserver GetLegendGraphic not working for single rule

Tags: geoserver, style, sld, getlegendgraphic

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>Parcel</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>Parcels</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <MinScaleDenominator>100</MinScaleDenominator>
          <MaxScaleDenominator>6000</MaxScaleDenominator>          
          <PointSymbolizer>
             <Graphic>
               <Mark>
                 <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
                 <Fill>
                   <CssParameter name="fill">#CC3300</CssParameter>
                 </Fill>
               </Mark>
               <Size>6</Size>
             </Graphic>
           </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

This is my style file. I want to get legend graphic wit a query `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/PGIS/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic`

This is returning a circle but not include text:
[image]

Bu it should be like this:
[image]

If I add multiple rules, text label is appearing.

Comment: Try to give a title for the rule
 <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Title>your_title</Title>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you add **LEGEND_OPTIONS** parameter to your request and the value **forceLabels:on** then you can force GeoServer to draw the text for a single rule. 
Here is an example of a request:

http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=topp:states&STYLE=point&LEGEND_OPTIONS=forceLabels:on

Comment: This example doesn't print the label, currently. Not sure what's going on there!

Comment: That is because the title in the polygon SLD was removed in the demo server. If you change the STYLE parameter from polygon to point then you will see the label again.